# Rails nested querying through another association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following active record models:

```
class Jobs
  has_many :leads
end

class Lead
  has_many :messages, through :notification
end

class Notification
  has_many :messages
end

class Message
  # has a type column (varchar) containing either: email, sms
end
```

I am unsure about how to find all jobs which through its associations have messages which are not of type sms. Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could join your tables and set a where clause in order to filter those messages that are not sms.

May be something like this:

```
Jobs.joins(leads: [{ notifications: :messages }]).where("type <> 'sms'")
```

Check https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables for more information.

Comment: Or in Rails 5 `.where.not(message: { type: "sms"})`

Comment: That looks better! My answer was merely illustrative.

Answer (score 1):

As Bruno and Jedi pointed out, something like this may work:

```
Job.joins(leads: [{ notifications: :message }]).where.not(messages: {msg_type: 'sms'})
```

Note this uses singular model name for Job (not Jobs). And associations like:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :leads
end

class Lead < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :messages, through: :notifications
end

class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lead
  belongs_to :message
end

class Message < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notifications
  has_many :leads, through: :notifications
end
```

Not clear from your question whether you have all those associations set properly.